# Two SQL tables but show the data in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

The following two tables below should be combined to 1 and show only the Market, Count of Date_buy, and Count of Date_sell:

```
SELECT Market, macdb.Date_buy 
FROM Buy_orders_macd macdb 
JOIN SECTOR sec ON sec.Ticker = macdb.Name_buy 
WHERE macdb.Date_buy = '2020-02-18' 


SELECT Market, macds.Date_sell 
FROM Sell_orders_macd macds 
JOIN SECTOR sec ON sec.Ticker = macds.Name_sell 
WHERE macds.Date_sell = '2020-02-18'
```

The example output here would be:

```
Market    Count of Date_buy    Count of Date_sell
Market_1       3                     4
Market_2       2                     2
```

How could I go about it? I tried UNION ALL but that wasn't the way.
Some of the other data I have is Company Name

Comment: Not sure how to add query after the second query. Could you put up an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two queries with `UNION`, and use `SUM()` to count the rows from each, grouping by market.

```
SELECT Market, SUM(buy) AS `Count of Date_buy`, SUM(sell) AS `Count of Date_sell`
FROM (
    SELECT Market, 1 AS buy, 0 AS sell
    FROM Buy_orders_macd macdb 
    JOIN SECTOR sec ON sec.Ticker = macdb.Name_buy 
    WHERE macdb.Date_buy = '2020-02-18'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Market, 0 AS buy, 1 AS sell
    FROM Sell_orders_macd macds
    JOIN SECTOR sec ON sec.Ticker = macds.Name_sell
    WHERE macds.Date_sell = '2020-02-18'
) AS x
GROUP BY Market
```